# Syntax error on token ";", , expected when initializing called value from another class

Tags: java, android, class

I have a value that I want to pass between 2 classes, but I get the following error:

> Syntax error on token ";", , expected when initializing called value
>   from another class

Class where I have the initial value

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    RandomMathQuestionGenerator question = new RandomMathQuestionGenerator();
    private static final String TAG= "Sudoku";

    public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = 
            "org.example.sudoku.difficulty";
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_NOVICE = 1;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_EASY = 2;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM = 3;
    public static final int DIFFICULTY_GURU = 4;

    public int value = 0;

    private GameView gameView;  

    public Game()
    {
       if (KEY_DIFFICULTY == String.valueOf(1))
        {
            value = 2; 
        }
        else if (KEY_DIFFICULTY == String.valueOf(2))
        {
            value = 3;        
        }
        else if (KEY_DIFFICULTY == String.valueOf(3))
        {
            value = 4;
        }
        else if (KEY_DIFFICULTY == String.valueOf(4))
        {
            value = 6;
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");    



    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {           
          //code here       
    }
}
```

Class where I call the value

```
public class RandomMathQuestionGenerator {

Game num = new Game();
int number = 0;
number = num.Game(value);
//public int number = 0;
//number = num.Game(number); 


private static final int NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS = 1;
    private static final int MIN_QUESTION_ELEMENTS = 2;
    private final int MAX_QUESTION_ELEMENTS = number;
    private static final int MIN_QUESTION_ELEMENT_VALUE = 1;
    private static final int MAX_QUESTION_ELEMENT_VALUE = 100;
    private final Random randomGenerator = new Random();    

    //rest of irrelevant code below
    }
```

Comment: remove the `public` in `public Game num`. And show us your Game class

Comment: `int number = 0;` and then on the next line `number = num.Game(value);`... Seems mighty pointless.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have included the Game class

Comment: @ChrisCooney technically true, i could do int number = num.Game(value) i guess

Comment: If that public keyword is inside a method body, it is invalid syntax. So as previously stated, remove it.

Comment: @MaciejCygan there is no `Game()` method in `Game` class like here `num.Game(value)`. Why would you instantiate an Activity class?

Comment: Please share the code of the second class where you are calling it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have created now Game()method, will update code accordingly

Comment: @Ankit i have added the second class

Comment: This line `number = num.Game(value);` cannot exist outside of an Initializer block. There's a lot going wrong with your code.

Comment: I might sound harsh here, but is this your first go at an Android application?

Comment: @Ole yes it is my first android app

Comment: Ok :) Classes that extends `Activity` are not meant to be initialized by you like normal generic java classes. Check out Sam's answer!

Comment: Also, if you haven't check out [this](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html), you probably should ;)

Comment: @Ole Yeah i can see that it doesn't work the same as normal generic java class. I am trying to find solution based on Sam answer, but i dont really seem to be getting anywhere. I do get some error i am not familiart with (errors found in comment under sam answer )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error is irrelevant in the long run.

In Android your *must* start an Activity with an Intent. (See [this Developer's Guide article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity).)  When you want to start Game use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

Also you declare `KEY_DIFFICULTY` as `final` (unchangeable):

```
public static final String KEY_DIFFICULTY = "org.example.sudoku.difficulty";
```

So your if-else block will never be true in any of these cases:

```
if (KEY_DIFFICULTY == String.valueOf(1))
```

*And* to compare Strings in Java you *must* use `equals()`, `==` will give inaccurate results. ([How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1267661))

---

If you want to pass the level of difficulty from one Activity to another use the Intent's extras, a `public` class variable, or another approach found in: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2091465/1267661)

---

**Addition**
You just added more code to your question and you have circular logic.

```
- When you create RandomMathQuestionGenerator object, you will create a Game object
    - When you create Game object, you will create a RandomMathQuestionGenerator object
        - When you create RandomMathQuestionGenerator object, you will create a Game object
            - When you create Game object, you will create a RandomMathQuestionGenerator object
                - When you create RandomMathQuestionGenerator object, you will create a Game object
                    - When you create Game object, you will create a RandomMathQuestionGenerator object
                        - When you create RandomMathQuestionGenerator object, you will create a Game object
                            - When you create Game object, you will create a RandomMathQuestionGenerator object
                                - ...
```

This will only stop when your app throws a StackOverflowException.

Comment: Im am trying to work way around with the Intent, but i am not succeeding. Your example throws an error  "The constructor Intent(RandomMathQuestionGenerator, Class<Game>) is undefined" and " The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type RandomMathQuestionGenerator"

Answer (score 0):

```
number = num.Game(value);
```

I don't see a method `Game(int value)` in your `Game` class. You need to create this method in your class:

```
public int Game(int value){
   //code
}
```

I am also not sure you can name a method the same name as your class. I assume the fact it has a return value in the signature, it would be valid, but it would be bad practice to have a method name the same as your class anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### Case - In `<init>`

Here's my modified proposed code for `RandomMathQuestionGenerator`:

```
public class RandomMathQuestionGenerator {
  private Game num;
  private int number;

  public RandomMathQuestionGenerator() {
    num = new Game();
    number = num.value;
    // Existing code here
  }
  // Existing code here
}
```

### Case - In method code

```
Game num = new Game();
int number = num.value;
```

Here's what's wrong:

- `public Game` - `public` is a *field* modifier, not a *variable* modifier, and is invalid in the middle of method code. Note that `final` is a valid modifier - it means that re-assigning the variable is a compile error.
- Creating number with a placeholder value, then assigning to it - that `0` will never be used
- num does not have a method Game, and value is not defined in this code. value is a property of Game objects, of which num is one. I **strongly** recommend renaming this variable - maybe `gameInst` would work.

### Summary

(in progress)

Comment: Turns out his `public Game num` is actually a field.

Comment: although your solution is not showing any errors in the code (i.e. red cross, underline etc) when i lunch application it crashes throwing errors